# Why is an element found using getElementById in Next.js returning null even when document is defined?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Using SSR in my React/Next app.

Trying to find an element with the id but is returning null

even when document is present (and I can see the div with the id plTable),

and even when getElementById is called after 6 seconds to ensure the element has been loaded on screen.

What is the issue and how can I fix this?

Here is the component:

```
const LineItemTable: React.FC<LineItemTableProps> = ({ reportName }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({});
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(0);

  const selectedCompanyId = useSelector((state) => state.company.selectedId);
  const company = useSelector((state) => state.company.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (reportName && selectedCompanyId) {
      dispatch(
        getReportByName({
          name: reportName, // 'profit and loss' or 'balance sheet'
          includeLineItems: true,
          page: page,
        }),
      );
    }
  }, [reportName, selectedCompanyId]);

  let plTable: any = 'kk';

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('uef');
    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        plTable = document.querySelector('plTable');// ***** NEVER FOUND ******
        console.log('doc', document); // ***** is found and defined correctly *****
        console.log('plTable', plTable); // ***** null *****
      }, 6000);
    }
  });

  const endObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      const [entry] = entries;
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
        //Put what you want to happen if the end is NOT visible
        console.log('not visible');
      } else {
        //Put what you want to happen if the end is visible
        //For instance firing your function
        // setPage(page + 1);
        console.log('visible');
      }
    },
    { root: null, threshold: 1 },
  );
  // endObserver.observe(plTable);

  const getLineItems = useMemo(() => makeGetAllLineItemsByReport(reportName), [
    reportName,
  ]);

  const lineItems = useSelector((state) => getLineItems(state));

  if (!lineItems) return null;

  // ADDED
  // Add an elemnt in your html with the class of "end" at the end of the chart
  // I recommend adding an empty div with the class of "end" and setting it's opacity to 0

  return (
    <div
      id="plTable" // ****** Defined here *******
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        margin: 'auto 0px',
      }}
    >
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Card
            sx={{
              padding: '20px',
            }}
          >
            <CardContent
              sx={{
                alignItems: 'center',
                display: 'flex',
                height: '1000px',
              }}
            >
              <Scrollbar className={classes.scrollBar}>
                <Table className={classes.root}>
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      <th>
                        <TableCell className={classes.headerStyle}>
                          ANALYSIS CATEGORY
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell
                          className={classes.headerStyle}
                          sx={{ marginRight: '10px' }}
                        >
                          NAME
                        </TableCell>
                        {company &&
                          company.dates.map((header) => (
                            <TableCell
                              className={classes.headerStyle}
                              sx={{
                                width: '200px !important',
                                marginLeft: '10px',
                              }}
                              key={header}
                            >
                              {header}
                            </TableCell>
                          ))}
                      </th>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <TableBody>
             
                    {lineItems.map((lineItem, i) => (
                      <TableRow key={lineItem.id}>
                        <LineItemRow
                          i={i}
                          id={lineItem.id}
                          reportName={reportName}
                          level={lineItem.level}
                        />
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
             
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>
              </Scrollbar>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Not a solution, but using a queryselector in react is normally a smell

Comment: @NickBailey Oh yes, but I have tried getElementById and className as well..

Comment: @Jake.K I prefer use from useRef hook

Comment: In React you want to use refs not DOM selectors, but I think your problem is in the selector string, what is `p1Table`. If you write it like that that looks for a `tag`. If it's an `id` you need to search for `#p1Table`

Answer (score 4):

Don't use DOM selectors in React, use `refs` to access DOM nodes.
You can create a ref with `useRef` or `React.createRef` or you can pass a callback to the `ref` attribute of an element, that will receive the DOM node reference when the virtual DOM has done with the reconciliation.

To check if the node is mounted and do something with it being sure it is mounted, try this:

```
 <div
      id="plTable" // ****** Defined here *******
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        margin: 'auto 0px',
      }}
      ref={node => {
        if (node) console.log("p1Table", node)
        //Do something with node
      }}
 >
```

Comment: thank you, will try the solution. I'm curious, what is the reason why dom selectors should be avoided in React, though?

Comment: Because React does not paint to the real DOM directly, it makes use of a virtual DOM, so you might meet weird behaviours and inconsistencies when trying to target a DOM node directly wirth a selector. 1- https://en.reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html 
2- https://en.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 3):

According to MDN docs, `querySelector` either takes an element to look for:

```
querySelector('plTable')
/* Looking for html tag plTable */
```

or an identifier:

```
querySelector('#plTable')
/* Looking for an element with id of plTable */
```